# Conditional in past tense narration

Tags: conditional-constructions, reported-speech

Let's suppose we have a sentence:

> If I see John I will tell him you are looking for him.

Now how should I put it in reported speech in the past? Like this:

> Mike said that if he ***saw*** (?) John he ***would*** tell him I ***was*** (?) looking for him.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly how you should phrase it for past reported speech.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. But you can write the following way too.

> If he saw John, Mike said, he would tell him I was looking for him.

It depends on "emphatic purposes".

Comment: That doesn't work well for me. It looks like you've put in a comma inappropriately to this sentence: *If he saw John, Mike said he would tell him O was looking for him*

Answer (score 0):

Just brainstorming here. Let's assume the fact that there could have been chances for Mike *having seen John*, this could be a case of *future in the past*. How about

> Mike said that if he **sees** John, he would tell him I was looking for him.

Comment: When it comes with the present simple, the tense is not normally changed. (For example: facts, regular actions, etc.) So normally you do the backshift like the OP's example.

Comment: I believe it should be "saw"